# How to change the title text on the Magento sales email?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, email-templates

How can I change the title text on the sale email?

I always get this in my email when I make an order,

```
Main Website Store: New Order # 100000016
```

I want to change it to,

```
[Name of my Store]: New Order # 100000016
```

Is it possible? where can I change it?

Also, in the sale email content,

> Thank you for your order from Main Website Store. Once your package
>   ships we will send an email with a link to track your order. If you
>   have any questions about your order please contact us at
>   support@example.com or call us at Monday - Friday, 8am - 5pm PST.
>
> Your order confirmation is below. Thank you again for your business.

Where can I change all this? Especially `Main Website Store`?

Comment: In admin, go to `System` > `Manage Stores`. Click on the `Store Name` (middle column) entry for your store and edit the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new order template files is located in

```
app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html
```

and

```
app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html
```

You can edit these files directly, but it's better to create an overwrite in the Magento Backend:

```
System -> Transactional Emails -> Add New Template
```

and then choose New Order / New Order for Guest, click load template and edit the mail template. Template Subject will look like:

```
{{var store.getFrontendName()}}: New Order # {{var order.increment_id}}
```

Change this to:

```
[Name of my store]: New Order # {{var order.increment_id}}
```

Comment: where can I find the data for `{{var store.getFrontendName()}}` in the backoffice?

Comment: Edit `Store Name` at `System -> Configuration -> General -> Store information`

Answer (score 4):

Go to System -> Configuration

Under the General Tab click General and select Shop Information. Enter the name of your store here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an email override extension such as https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/email-override. This allows you to override email templates in code rather than having to do it through the database. Makes it much easier to manage, transport to other stores, and is independent of core updates.